# Why does this cable have 3 wires to PCB on one side but only 2 wires on the other end?

Tags: pcb, amplifier, audio, circuit-design, soldering

I am working on a stereo receiver and was going to resolder some wiring. When I went to strip one wire on the 3-wire cable, the whole wire pulled out that was bare except for the half inch I was going to strip off of. There were only 2 wires on other end soldered to the PCB. The 3-sided part I was going to reattach to PCB each had a different pin to solder to.

Comment: Please add photos

Comment: The 3rd wire may be the screen. The boards may be earthed via different cables : the screen is then connected at one end only to prevent an earth loop which would pick up magnetic hum.

Comment: Thank you so much, I kinda suspected maybe a ground but your comment makes so much sense . My main concern was can I fix it and yes can do. The stereo is a Pioneer SX 1250   160wpc     thank you . you people are great.....

Answer (score 1):

It could be a 2-core shielded cable, with the shield wired only at the PCB end to avoid hum loops.

Here's one such example of 'Line in' RCA jacks, on a metal chassis, wired to a preamplifier PCB.

[image]